# Does Spring Boot 1 Actuator work in external Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, external, spring-boot-actuator

When running Spring boot 1.5.4 application (created to test this scenario) with embedded tomcat, I'm able to access the actuator endpoints. but when i run a spring boot application 1.5.4 which is a project at my work in external tomcat(this project contains spring-boot-starter-jersey), the end points are not working. i'm getting 404 on hitting the url (`http:localhost:8080/{{war name}}/{{application-path}}/health` , here the application-path is the path which i have used in JerseyConfig class `@ApplicationPath("/sample")`).

Please correct if i'm missing anything.

Comment: If you are using the correct means of configuration then yes it should work. The fact that you have a `JerseyConfig` and map that makes me wonder if your setup if even correct (looks like you are bypassing Spring Boot and simply bootstrap Jersey instead of letting Spring Boot handle that).

Comment: simply bootstrap Jersey??!! Please elaborate.

my JerseyConfig class looks lyk this..        
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
 public JerseyConfiguration() {

  register(BookController.class);
  register(GenericExceptionMapper.class);
 }
}

Comment: Does your `@SpringBootApplication` class extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`. Also the application path doesn't influence where your health indicators are deployed, that is only for Jersey.

Comment: ThnQQ for quick response. Instead of @SpringBootApplication annotation. we are using below annotations on top of the class which extends `SpringBootServletIntializer` class are

`@Configuration
@Import({ ***.class, **.class, **.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "**.**.**.**")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ImportResource({ "classpath:spring/concert-security-jersey-context.xml",
  "classpath:spring/security-datasource-context.xml" })
@EnableJms
@EnableCaching
@PropertySource("classpath:common.properties")`

Comment: So you aren't using Spring Boot. You disabled auto configuration and as such actuator isn't being loaded.

Comment: Ok.. Is there any way to get actuators run without using auto configuration?

Comment: Why did you disable it in the first place? Looks like you don't want to use Spring Boot at all? Import the configuration for it (but not sure if that is enough as you will mis some health indicators. metrics etc. etc.).

Comment: my seniors created this application without enabling autoconfiguration. When i enable it, some other are breaking which are causing the application to fail on start up.

Comment: Basically you are bypassing most of the features and bonuses you get with Spring Boot. One of those being auto configuration of things which you now all do manually. Nonetheless adding the manual configuration for the actuator will start it, but that might be a search on what to add as you will need to add the different health indicators, metrics etc. as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177782/discussion-between-bandham-manikanta-and-m-deinum).